# Using the Compare-Object in PowerShell, is there a way to make a comparison output based on alternative conditions?

Tags: xml, powershell, comparison

I'm writing a script that will compare a server configuration against baseline configuration as well as against a parallel server. Settings the script will check for include software versions, RAM allocation, directory locations, and free storage space, among other things.

My plan is to use three XML files; one for the baseline, one for the reference server, and one for the difference server.

The issue is, not every check on the configuration will be for equality. Used storage for example is based on a percent of total space, directory checks will need to ignore certain characters, etc.

What would be the best way for me to approach this problem? Is there a way in the XML itself for me to make it dynamic? Would there be a decent way for me to change the XML values in the code? Is there another better angle I'm not thinking of?

Example:

```
Baseline:
- 
- 
Port               - 1234  
Minimum Memory     - =< 75% of total RAM  
Default Data Dir   - E:\Data  

Server to check:
Total RAM          - 12
SQL Server Version - Microsoft SQL Server 2008
Port               - 1234
Minimum Memory     - 10
Default Data Dir   - E:\Directory\Data

Comparing server:
Total RAM          - 8
SQL Server Version - Microsoft SQL Server 2012
Port               - 1234
Minimum Memory     - 6
Default Data Dir   - E:\Data


Output:
Server to check:
Total RAM          - DIFF FROM COMPARING SERVER
SQL Server Version - DIFF FROM BASELINE
Port               - PASS
Minimum Memory     - DIFF FROM BASELINE
Default Data Dir   - DIFF FROM BASELINE
```

Comment: Can you give even pseudo-code examples of what you're trying to do? It is not clear to me what you are hoping to get as output. Examples would be excellent (server properties, baseline properties, "alternate" properties, and expected output).

Comment: @TheMadTechnician sorry about that, added a very general example of what I would like the script to do. Also when I say alternate conditions, I mean rather than simply checking for equality, checking for greater than/less than, equality in subsections of a string, etc.

Comment: I would extract all information from both servers (live, why through an XML file?), and then apply conditions field by field, including the baseline checks (you can load values from an XML file here if you want to take the configuration out, adding the reference server name for example). Not sure `Compare-Object` would be customizable enough to help you.

Comment: @sodawillow XML file because I figured that would the best for comparing, but it's not necessary. I just need the server configuration I'm checking to output to a file with all of the flags added.

Comment: Both have 12Gb as total memory, but I see your point anyway :) I'm trying to write an example script to show you my approach

Comment: @sodawillow that's what I get for multi-tasking! :) fixed it again just for my peace of mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#can be taken from XML file
$freeMemoryPercentRequirement = 75

$referenceServer = [PSCustomObject]@{

    Name = "Server01"
    TotalMemory = 0
    FreeMemoryPercent = 0

}

$targetServer = [PSCustomObject]@{

    Name = "Server44"
    TotalMemory = 0
    FreeMemoryPercent = 0

}

$results = [PSCustomObject]@{

    Name = $targetServer.Name
    TotalMemory = ""
    FreeMemoryPercent = ""

}

foreach($server in $referenceServer,$targetServer) {
    $server.TotalMemory = (Get-WmiObject -computerName $server.Name -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).TotalPhysicalMemory / 1024
    $server.FreeMemoryPercent = "{0:N0}" -f ((Get-WmiObject -computerName $server.Name -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).FreePhysicalMemory / $server.TotalMemory * 100)
}

if($targetServer.TotalMemory -eq $referenceServer.TotalMemory) {
    $results.TotalMemory = "CHECK!"
} else {
    $results.TotalMemory = "FAILED"
}

if($targetServer.FreeMemoryPercent -ge $freeMemoryPercentRequirement ) {
    $results.FreeMemoryPercent = "CHECK!"
} else {
    $results.FreeMemoryPercent = "FAILED"
}

$results | fl *
```

Sample output :

```
Name              : Server44
TotalMemory       : CHECK!
FreeMemoryPercent : FAILED
```

I am in a rush and cannot add comments for now, I'll try to edit later. Tell me if this matches what you need ^^.

Comment: That looks great! I'll mess around with it and see what happens. Thank you!